# Cannot find table v$parameter in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to get the number of sessions in Oracle using the SQL query:

```
SELECT value FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'sessions'
```

But I get this error:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
SELECT value FROM v$parameter WHERE name = 'sessions'
Error at Command Line:1 Column:18
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Maybe the Oracle user that I use is not privileged?

Comment: If you don't have the required privileges, you can still read the parameter values using dbms_utility.get_parameter_value. See explanation and example at: http://oraclequirks.blogspot.com/2007/10/dbmsutilitygetparametervalue.html

Comment: @DavidBalažic the `dbms_utility.get_parameter_value( param_key, result_int, result_varchar )`-approach did not work for me (Ora v19c): *SQL-error [1031] [42000]: ORA-01031: insufficient rights -
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 140 -
ORA-06512: in "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 125*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally the better approach is to use a procedure and grant the necessary privileges to this procedure. However if you want use SQL directly, you can grant `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` or `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` to the user.

Answer (score 5):

Probably. To grant the rights, you need to use the table name as `V_$PARAMETER`. It comes from some restriction when granting rights on dynamic views.

Comment: I changed the name of the table as you recommended but I again get the same error message.

Comment: @PeterPenzov: you don't need to change the name, you need to **grant** the privileges on the table that plouf mentioned.

Comment: What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: @PeterPenzov you'd run, as sys, `grant select on v_$parameter to youruser;` where `youruser` is the name of the user you're trying to run the select as.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SQL directly (referring to the second option in the accepted answer)

As of Feb 2023, using Oracle version 19, this works...

Connect as SYSTEM and run

```
grant SELECT ANY DICTIONARY to <user>;
```

But SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE didn't work for me...

<s>grant SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE to ...;</s>

There are documented differences between the two here:
http://www.petefinnigan.com/weblog/archives/00001461.htm

This is where the author gives the following info and **warning**:

Well, SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE allows access to some things Oracle deemed not allowed by SELECT ANY DICTIONARY so we need to be careful of granting this role on these grounds. BUT, the overwhelming issue for me is that SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE gives access to 4539 objects and SELECT ANY DICTIONARY gives access to 6228 objects (both numbers in 18c XE)

I am not sure why Oracle do not publish the full list of exclusions in SELECT ANY DICTIONARY but they do publish all of the main tables. We can easily find out anyway. For me, i want to know what does SELECT ANY DICTIONARY really mean. I want to know what i am actually granting if I give out that privilege; well it means access to 6228 tables and views in 18cXE

**Both of these rights should not be used; they are a sledgehammer to crack a peanut. If someone needs access to V$SESSION or V$DATABASE and there is a legitimate reason to have that access then grant access on the individual views not SELECT ANY DICTIONARY or SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE.**

Answer (score -4):

using the privileges: - *select any table*, *alter any table* when running the grant as SYS with SYSDBA in Oracle 12c solved the issue for me.

Comment: This is dangerous as it grants more than is necessary.